# Link between two functions in a different class

Tags: python, function, class, oop

I am new to Python and attempting to create a text-based adventure game and having some issues. The codes below are the representation what I'm stuck at the moment.

```
class A(object):
   def funct1(self):
      pass
   def funct2(self):
      pass

class B(object):
   def funct1(self):
      pass
```

I attempted to link from class B funct1 to class A funct2, which was unsuccessful. Although I understand link between functions within each function of a class (e.g `self.funct2()`), link between functions in different classes is still unclear for me.

I tried to use `def __init__` but I'm not sure how it applies in this case. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "link"?

Comment: do you mean inheritance?

Comment: Something like inheritance, yes. But I'm not too sure in this case since I'm not clear which one would be the parent.

What I meant by link is, in my game I plan to get a storyline moving from one and another. An option in def funct1 in class B will lead to def funct2 in class A.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [inheritance](http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/object_oriented_programming.html#inheritance) if you want to use methods from A in class B:

```
class A(object):
   def funct1(self):
      print("Hello from func1")

   def funct2(self):
      print("Hello from  func2")

class B(A):
    pass

b = B()
b.funct2()
b.funct1()
Hello from  func2
Hello from  func1
```

Now to  call the inherited  methods in class `B` you simply use `self.func1(), self.func2()..`

If you want func1 to behave differently in class `B` you can override the method:

```
class A(object):
   def funct1(self):
      print("Hello from A class func1")

   def funct2(self):
      print("Hello from A class func2")

class B(A):
    def funct1(self):
        print("overridden method")


b = B()
b.funct2()
b.funct1()

Hello from A class func2
overridden method
```

If you want your instances to have a name attribute create the attribute in the `__init__` method:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def funct1(self):
      print("Hello from A class func1")

    def funct2(self):
      print("Hello from A class func2")

class B(A):
    def funct1(self):
        print("overridden method")


b = B("bar")  
print(b.name)
bar
```

There is a nice tutorial on classes in the python-practice-book link I provided, I suggest you check it out.

Answer (score 0):

to access to functions in other class are pretty easy in python you just need to state the ClassName . functionName () 
here is one eaxample :

```
class A(object):
   def funct1(self):
      pass
   def funct2(self):
      pass

class B(object):
   def funct1(self):
      pass
B.funct1()
```

Classname.functionName(Object)

Answer (score -1):

I hope I'm understanding your question. It sounds like you're trying to call `A.func1()` from `B.func1()`. The problem with this question is that class `A` has no information about `B` unless you utilize inheritance.

You could utilize inheritance, however another solution to this would be to have `B.func1()` accept an instance of `A` as an argument.

For an example of this kind of interaction think about how an Accountant interacts with an Invoice. The invoice doesn't inherit anything from the Accountant, and the same thing the other way around. All the accountant needs to do is take the invoice and activate the `Pay` method.

```
class Invoice():
    amount_due = 100

    def pay(self, payment_method):
        pass

class Accountant():
    def pay_invoice(self, invoice, payment_method):
        if invoice.amount_due > 0:
                invoice.pay(payment_method)
```

The `Accountant` class doesn't need to know anything about the `Invoice` class other than it has a `Pay` method that takes a `payment_method`. The `Invoice` class doesn't care who pays it as long as someone does.